# Do I have the right IpTables here? I cannot send but I can receive

Tags: iptables, postfix, firewall, smtp

Setting up a mailserver and I've taken steps to secure it. One of the steps is to have a set of IPTABLES rules 
From you can see, I've set all the policies to DROP, even the OUTPUT, I think that's good. 
I'm a beginner at this, so you'll probably see rules that are not needed. Feel free to point them out please, I'm scared of becoming a relay.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 143 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 143 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 587 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 587 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 587 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " - 
-log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, congrats, this is a great first stab at a ruleset.

For instance, you're allowing the correct source ports inbound and the correct destination ports outbound for traffic involved in outbound mail to flow, and vice versa.

It looks like state is tripping you up.  Rather than this pattern to your rules (using the smtp port as an example, since it's the source of your symptoms, although the pattern I'm suggesting  will work for imap and the rest):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This pattern should work:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You'll note, in addition to adding the "RELATED" state, I flipped the state matching conditions of the last 2 rules.

The only ports I'm questioning are port 80.  Are you offering up a webserver?  If so, think about switching to https.  Perhaps an admin console?  If so, think about limiting the source IPs or something like that.

Just a tip -  you can run `iptables -L -n -vvv` and, in addition to line numbers for each rule, iptables will tell you how many packets have matched each rule since it was loaded.  You can often use that to ascertain which rule is causing you problems, by recreating the symptoms and watching which counters fail to increment.

Also, caveat emptor: I wrote this off the top of my head, on my phone; so don't hesitate to ask if a bit doesn't test out - I can validate my work when I get to my laptop.

Comment: Hello, I didn't get an email notification about your reply, I came to check on the question and saw your response. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'm going to read your post carefully and get back to you after some testing. 

Thanks again.